# schedule event time showing issue

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i have problem in schedule. it is not showing time of event. like below image. [image]i am using primefaces3.0M4-snapshot and jsf2.0

following is code

In bean

```
private ScheduleModel eventModel; 

public ForNewSchedule()
{
System.out.println("KSHITITJ");
Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
c1.set(2012, 04, 01, 05, 05, 05);

Calendar c2=Calendar.getInstance();
c2.set(2012, 04, 01, 06, 06, 06);

Calendar c3=Calendar.getInstance();
c3.set(2012, 04, 04, 10, 10, 10);

Calendar c4=Calendar.getInstance();
c4.set(2012, 04, 04, 11, 11, 11);

eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel(); 
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", c1.getTime(), c2.getTime())); 
eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party",c3.getTime(),c4.getTime())); 
System.out.println("KSHITITJ-----");
}
```

on page

```
<h:form> 
<p:schedule value="#{forNewSchedule.eventModel}" /> 
</h:form>
```

thanks,

Comment: not sure it was showing the time in 3.04 , for a quick check , try a newer version , like 3.0 final...

Comment: check folowing link. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf. it is not version problem.

Comment: the screen shot is from primefaces website and in your example you don't see the time? what do you see than?

Comment: ok. check this link. i putted twi screen shots of my page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022515/primefaces-schedule-time-not-showing-on-week

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure , but almost... they added the display of time in the scheduler after 3.04 rls , so if you upgrade to a more up to date version you should get what you to... (unlike you I didn't want that feature so I had to remove it myself after one of primefaces upgrades

I remember doing it by

```
.fc-event-time{
display:none;
}
```

so in theory you should add something like to your css

```
.fc-event-time {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but again... I think you first should try to upgrade to a more up to date version of primefaces

Comment: thanks for reply. i add that but it is not working. and i can not change version because it is creating lots of problem. like in lightBox component. <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="95%" height="95%">. now in 3.2 it is not getting height and width in %. this type of lots of problems are there.

Comment: Ok, You can always create a new project with  3.2 of primefaces an build a single page to check out the scheduler time issue once and for all..

Comment: yes. i checked that schedule thing in 3.2 and it is working perfact. the problem is in 3.0-M4 snapshot.