# primefaces schedule time not showing on week

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

this is my problem. it is not showing time when i am clicking on week.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

:)

Look at the Calendar again...

Your month view of April shows the beginning of May as well..

So its a 1/5 and 4/5  events are actually belongs to May

While the week display shows you the first week of April....  you should advance the week view further to the beginning of May... there you should see the events of 1/5 and 4/5